# Managing permissions and folder structure for vsftp server configuraton

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

I am going to develop a photo-selling webapp, where every user has options to upload their photos via ftp (Ubuntu 10.04 + vsftpd).

This is my folder structure:

```
/var/www/project/downloads_ftp_folder
/var/www/project/downloads_ftp_folder/user1_ftp_folder
/var/www/project/downloads_ftp_folder/user2_ftp_folder
/var/www/project/downloads_ftp_folder/user3_ftp_folder
...
```

For every user I am creating an ftp folder and group

Is my strategy is correct? How can I create a super user who can manage all the `ftp_folder` directories (eg `user1_ftp_folder`,`user2_ftp_folder`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add the super user to every group or

user1_group = user1, superuser

user2_group = user2, superuser

...

```
chown user1:user1_group user1_ftp_folder
chown user2:user2_group user2_ftp_folder
...
chmod 770 user1_ftp_folder
```

do not bother having user groups and just have a superuser group

supergroup = superuser

```
chown user1:supergroup user1_ftp_folder
chown user2:supergroup user2_ftp_folder
...
chmod 770 user1_ftp_folder
```